# Teredo allowing for IPv6 access and resolving IPv6-only domains in nslookup and ping, but not in any web browsers

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, teredo

so I am running with Teredo for my IPv6 setup (yes, I'm aware that this is perhaps suboptimal, but it is the best I can do with what I have, so don't lambast me, please).

I have a perfectly good connection to the IPv6 network. I have a public IPv6 address; when I go to http://test-ipv6.com, I get a 7/10 (full access to IPv6, but my computer prefers v4 when it can get it). Likewise, other IPv6 testing sites generally work as well.

In addition to this, I am also able to use my web browser (Firefox, although I've tried Chrome and found the same behavior) to access IPv6-only sites... by IP address. However, when trying IPv6-only sites, such as http://ipv6.google.com, I am unable to connect, with messages that DNS did not resolve. In comparison, using `ping` or `nslookup`, I can actually access these sites, and these network tools work fine even with those IPv6-only domains.

My setup is using Google's Public DNS for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a solution in the form of a registry edit: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b0d80a91-4bee-4265-b4fc-9fb70568b2f4/dns-behavior-and-teredo?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you this is by design. Modern Windows versions block Teredo when looking up hostnames using DNS. Teredo is only used when connecting to an IPv6 address and the computer has no other way to reach it. In that case it will try Teredo as a last resort.

Microsoft has been sunsetting Teredo for a while now, and to be honest I'm surprised it still works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sander Steffann said:

> Microsoft has been sunsetting Teredo for a while now, and to be honest I'm surprised it still works at all.

The answer to this (as I found last week) is that Microsoft has discontinued their own (default) Teredo servers and you have to configure Teredo to use a 3rd party server instead. I used `teredo.trex.fi`, but there may well be others.

My own prediction is that the need for Teredo might actually get greater in the next few years rather than reduce. The logic is as follows:

1. Until now, almost all IPv6 internet connected systems have also had IPv4 addresses. But as of December 2019 these are officially exhausted (though there may still be some ISPs who have addresses they have been allocated still available to give to users). We are therefore going to see a massive growth in IPv6-only systems.
2. The vast majority of systems (esp. end user systems) are still IPv4 only, with both ISPs only supporting IPv4 and their home routers etc. being IPv4 only, and although more and more ISPs will start to provide IPv6 services I still expect there to be large number of IPv4-only systems for at least another decade.
3. There will therefore be a big need for gateway technologies to allow IPv4-only systems to connect-to and communicate-with IPv6-only systems. These can either be provided by the ISPs or if not individual users will need to implement them e.g. using Teredo.

I suspect, therefore, that reports of the death of Teredo have been exaggerated.